# Cannot get ngForm date value from datepicker in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, mat-datepicker

I can not get value from `mat-datepicker`. It says `undefined`. I used `ngForm` and `ngModel` but I do not know where I am wrong.

```html
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="registerClient(f.value)">
    <div class="" style="width: 50%; margin:auto;">
        <!-- ... Other fields -->
        <!-- ... -->

        <div class="form-group">
            <mat-form-field id="date">
                <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="date">
                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                <mat-datepicker id="datePicked" #picker></mat-datepicker>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-success mt-2">Add new client</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**client-form.ts**

```js
export class ClientFormComponent {
    date: Date;
    // ...
    // ...
    registerClient(crediantials) {
        let client: Client = {
            firstName: crediantials.firstName,
            lastName: crediantials.lastName,
            phone: crediantials.phone,
            doctorsName: this.selectedD.username,
            procedure: this.selectedP,
            registrationDate: this.date
        };

        console.log(client), 'client';
        console.log(crediantials)
        console.log(this.date, ' date);
        this.clientService.addClient(client);
    }
}
```

These are the errors I get in my console.

> ClientFormComponent.html:41 ERROR Error: If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form
>         control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.
>
> Example 1: `<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" name="first">`
>
> Example 2: `<input [(ngModel)]="person.firstName" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">`
>
> ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 69, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
>
> ERROR Error: ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

This is the line where the error occurs.

```html
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date"  [(ngModel)]="date">
```

Comment: Can you please make a snippet using stackblitz.com

Comment: can you make it in stackblitz ?

Comment: I added error lines. There are too many dependencies what should I add to make stackblitz work

Comment: <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" name="date" placeholder="Choose a date"  [(ngModel)]="date"> will resolve it

Answer (score 0):

If ngForm is used, input fields which have ngModal must have an attribute name with a value.

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" name="date" placeholder="Choose a date" [(ngModel)]="date">
```